# How to remove duplicate items from two lists consecutively

Tags: python, list

I have the below function which receives two lists as parameters.
Based on the condition, I want to remove items from the lists, but on running the code, the contents of the list remain unchanged. I have verified that the IF condition inside the WHILE loop is successful and code flow is reaching the DEL operation.

I referred to a similar question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71079753/python-del-operator-not-working-inside-for-loop] that we cannot remove items from the list while iterating it at the same time. But in my code I am not iterating the lists and have even used copies of lists. So what's wrong with my code?

```
def downsample(document, tags):
    i=0 
    doc_list=document.copy()
    tags_list=tags.copy()
    while i < len(tags)-3:
        if ((tags[i] == tags[i+1]) and (tags[i] == tags[i+2]) and (tags[i] == tags[i+3])):
          del tags_list[i:3]
          del doc_list[i:3]
        i = i+1
    
    return(doc_list, tags_list)
```

Comment: Not the actual answer to your question, but `else: pass` is useless. The `else` block is optional; if you have nothing to do in there, simply don't have one.

Comment: `del tags_list[i:3]` does *nothing* if `i` is greater than 2 - the second element of a slice is the end index, NOT a length.

Comment: Besides wrong slicing, as you delete items from copies, `i` won't align with the original ones anymore.

Comment: @gre_gor, I understand the slicing problem, could you guide me on how to fix this code?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve/improvise the code as below:

````
def remove_items(list1, list2, occurrence):
    """ Remove Consecutively Occurring Element from List1 and its index from List2 """
    indexes = []
    cnt = 0
    iter = 1
    while iter < len(list1):
        if list1[iter] == list1[iter - 1]:
            cnt += 1
            if cnt == occurrence - 1:
                indexes += [*range(iter - cnt, iter + 1, 1)]
                cnt = 0
                iter += 1
        else:
            cnt = 0
        iter += 1
    for item in range(len(indexes) - 1, -1, -1):
        del list1[indexes[item]]
        del list2[indexes[item]]
```
````